# How to fix this MemoryError: Unable to allocate in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, memory

Here is the code I have

```
out = out.T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum().T
```

and it gives this error

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 13.1 GiB for an array with shape (37281, 47002) and data type int64
```

I tried this

```
out = out.T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum().astype(np.int8).T
```

but still getting the same error!

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have creates some large temporary arrays.
You could probably do this operation in chunks, accumulate them and then merge the results.

```py
chunksize= int(1e4)  # or some other value
results = []
for i in range(0, len(out), chunksize):
    results.append(out[i:i+chunksize].T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum())
```

Answer (score 0):

An obvious thing to do, faced with a shortage of internal (RAM) storage,
is to use external storage instead.
Use [.to_sql()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)
to send the data to a sqlite or postgres RDBMS,
and then issue a sql GROUP BY, which *will* succeed -- no malloc failures.
Your filesystem is bigger than your installed DRAM.

A more subtle approach is what you tried,
in cases where we are *just barely* out of memory:
cast values to a smaller type.
This silently discards the more significant bits, if any values have them set.

```
out = out.T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum().astype(np.int8).T
```

You downcast a bit late, there.
So we compute lots of int64 temp results, and *then* truncate to byte.

Prefer

```
out = out.astype(np.int8).T.groupby(level=0, sort=False).sum().T
```

Better yet, if all values truly are small,
then use int8 as early in your pipeline as possible.
You're impacting cache hits and bus bandwidth
by moving around seven zero bytes
with each byte that contains "actual" data.